# Add a blur view over a table view in table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Upon clicking a button, I would like to be able to obscure the background (UITableViewController) with a Blur and Vibrancy visual effect when my overlay subview is added to the superview. Usually, I would drag and drop the visual effect in Main.storyboard, however, I cannot drag the effect onto a table view. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your code

Answer (score 3):

you can add a blur view on the main view in the following way

```
@IBAction func addBlur(_ sender: Any) {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
}
```

further more in the line

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
```

you can add the following effects

```
extraLight
light
dark
regular      //10.0 or higher
prominent    //10.0 or higher
```

further more you can use [this](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Blurable) open source library for more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

add the effect programatically heres a code snippet

```
 var darkBlur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect()
 darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light) //extraLight, light, dark
 let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
 blurView.frame = self.view.frame //your view that have any objects
 blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
 self.yourUIViewToBlur.addSubview(blurView)
```